# What's Chromecast's maximum supported frame rate?

Tags: chromecast

Is it possible to play 1080p videos (H.264) with 60 fps with Chromecast? The [specifications](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media) mention "H.264 High Profile Level 4.1, 4.2 and 5". Level 4.2 should support 1920x1080 up to 64 fps.

What frame rate is used for TV display?

What's the maximum frame rate a HTML5 receiver app can achieve?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend checking the Google Cast developer webpage for the answer to this question. https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media#video-codecs
Personally, from my own testing. I've discovered that the Chromecast and Chromecast v2 supports 720p @60fps and 1080p @30fps. A test I performed, thanks to a suggestion on reddit, was to use the test videos off Netflix which displays the current resolution and framerate of the streaming videos.

Answer (score 0):

I own a google chromecast. Yesterday I watched a full movie, which was stored in my local hard disk (using the videostream chrome extension), and it played at 1080p w/60fps. There were some rare frame drops because my connection sucks (I have 6 mb) although the main quality was excellent.

As for streaming/paid services, I have no clue.

Comment: Are you sure that the video was encoded with 60fps? Usually movies aren't recorded with such a high frame rate.